# Not able to load XML View

Tags: sapui5

I am going through the [Get started](http://openui5.org/getstarted.html) tutorial of OpenUI5 and using a notepad to enter javascript code. I am in step 3 - XML Views.

My folders are as follows

XML File App.view - copy paste from step 3

HTML file example - copy paste from step 3

When I run this I am getting an error which says

[image]

Unfortunately I cannot use any other tool due to customer restrictions. I can only use notepad.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Your issues is no related to the used editor. It seems that you are loading the index.html from your file system. Please use a local webserver to deliver it and open it using HTTP.

Comment: Thanks Matbtt.

[This works now][1]

But how do I view this from local host as my customer has restricted me from accessing https sites and I want to be able to see this from my local file system only.

Any shotcuts for this??

Thanks

KR


  [1]: http://bookfans.freecloudhost.xyz/example.html